# Ajax theme and wordpress head section

Tags: ajax, wordpress, enquire.js

My wordpress theme is responsive and is entirely loaded with ajax:

- mobile-page.php loads when window.width < 1080px
- desktop-page.php when window.width > 1080px.

At the moment it works like this:

- wp-templatepage-homepage.php calls homepage-js() which is a js-file
  included through wp_enqueue_script
- homepage-js() tests window.width and do an ajax call which dynamically loads the right php template file (Mobile / Desktop).

*This is working great* so far **but** the mobile version doesn't show up properly because I don't know how to put mobile.css into the head section of the website.

Comment: Are you trying to load a CSS file dynamically? AFAIK, that doesn't exist. You either use inline rules or load both files or combine the files, no?

Comment: Hey thank you brasofilo! Since I found really nothing on the argument, you might be right. Anyway I combined both files but when the mobile template loads, the stylesheet does not affect the page! [link]http://goo.gl/fxtLyk